# Javascript Stopwatch Insert into HTML

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I've been looking at this code:

http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-date-and-time-2/online-jquery-stopwatch/

I'm trying to understand exactly how it is working because I'd like a timer on a page I'm working on.

I can't for the life of me work out where the value of the timer is added to the input "disp" and how I could put this into a regular text, not a form input.

The only thing I can see that refers to it is:

```
t[6]=document.getElementById('disp');
```

Can anyone help me understand this please,

Thanks

Comment: the code is not jquery, its just good old plain javascript

Comment: removed the tag, sorry the site linking to the code mentioned jquery so I just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've correctly identified that they use t[6] to refer to the HTML element.  But to set it, earlier on there is:

```
function disp() {
    if (t[2]) t[1]=(new Date()).valueOf();
    t[6].value=format(t[3]+t[1]-t[0]);
}
```

Since `t[6]` is the form input, they set the `value` of the form input to the formatted time.  If you wanted to use some other element, e.g. `<div id="myTime"></div>`, you could say instead:

```
function disp() {
    if (t[2]) t[1]=(new Date()).valueOf();
    document.getElementById("myTime").innerText = format(t[3]+t[1]-t[0]);
}
```

Which changes only the last line, so that you may set the text of your `div`.

Comment: I should've seen that, I stared at it for long enough. I'm very grateful for the help, thanks.